# addEventListener that listens to the contents of an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, event-handling

**Background:** I have written a bookmarklet (JavaScript) that appends an iframe to the current page you are viewing. This iframe's src attribute is pointing to a form back on my application.

**Problem:** I am trying to utilize addEventListener to detect if that form has been submitted. However, I don't seem to be able to access the elements within the iframe.

For example:

```
document.getElementById(remote_form_id).addEventListener("submit",afterSubmit,true)
```

does not work because the getElementByID call is returning null.

My current work-around is to add an event listener on the iframe to listen for a "load" action and then call an intermediary function that ups a counter because I know how many times the iframe will be *loaded* before I need to call afterSubmit().

```
document.getElementById(marklet_iframe_id).addEventListener("load",listenForSubmit,true)

function listenForSubmit(){
    if (count==1){afterSubmit();}
    count++;
}
```

Basically, I'm looking for a best practice cause this is a crap approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it doesn't work in IE, you may want to look at the [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) method of the pages' window objects. It allows you to asynchronously send string data between windows, even when direct access would be forbidden by the same-origin policy.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. However, I'd rather have a bit of a work-around and accommodate for IE..

Comment: @anxiety: Actually, reading further, it seems that IE 8+ (not IE 7 or below) has support for postMessage (only between iframes, not between self-contained windows, but that part shouldn't be a problem for you).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var doc = document.getElementById(marklet_iframe_id).contentDocument;
var form = doc.getElementById(formId)
form.addEventListener("submit", afterSubmit, true)
```

Comment: This won't work if such access would violate the same-origin policy - if the two pages use different hostnames, port numbers, or protocols.

Comment: In my case, they are on two different hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [EasyXDM library](http://easyxdm.net/) which uses the best-available techniques in a given user's browser to achieve this.  It also is "best practice-y" in that its goal is to send messages between windows, and it's up to those windows to handle the messages, which mimicks the postMessage functionality available in HTML5 browsers.